# How to add key value pair in custom settings in Salesforce?

Tags: json, customsetting

I am trying to add key-value pair in the Custom settings, but I don't know how to add that in the custom settings in salesforce.?

```
    { label: 'ABC', value: 'ABC' },
    { label: 'CDE', value: 'CDE' },
    { label: 'FFF', value: 'FFF' },
    { label: 'NoSP', value: 'NoSP' }
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you want to save a JSON array in a single custom setting record? or do you want each object in OP to be a separate record in a custom setting ?

Answer (score 4):

Custom Settings records are basically the same as SObject records. To specifically create something in the vain of a key-value pair, you can just create two fields to hold that information. So the key would be entered in one field, and the value in the other field on the same record. Then if you're looking to leverage this custom setting in Apex, you'll just need to fetch the relevant custom setting records and create a map with that data, using the key field as the key of the map and the value field as its associated value.

Answer (score 0):

I first thought you could Create a Long Text Area field and store your data in it as a string. However, this is only supported in Custom Metadata Types, not Custom Settings as I thought, there is currently an Idea for this, otherwise, you will have to do as @Nicholas Savini mentions.

[Text Area (long) for Custom Settings](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0LpAAI)

Comment: probably downvoted because custom settings don't support text area long

Comment: I read the wrong doc / Idea, it is in custom metadata type records, not custom settings, updated my answer accordingly